# Airflow: Convert one digit to two digit with execution_date

Tags: python, date, airflow

I am trying to convert my airflow date from one digit to two digit. At the moment when I use `{{ execution_date.month }}` my month becomes `1` but would like it to become `01`.

I have tried with `{{ execution_date.month.strftime("%m") }}` but get the error:

> int object' has no attribute 'strftime

Comment: Try `execution_date.strftime("%m")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="bash_example",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 19),
    catchup=False
) as dag4:

    BashOperator(task_id="task", bash_command="echo {{ execution_date.strftime('%m') }}")
```

Or

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

@dag(schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 19), catchup=False)
def bash_example():
    BashOperator(task_id="task", bash_command="echo {{ execution_date.strftime('%m') }}")


dag = bash_example()
```

Rendering:

[image]

Logs:

[image]